# Evaluating on exponential functions

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I m stuck on a question on evaluation on exponential functions.

The question is as follows:

Define $x(a) = (e^{ma})(\sin a)$ and $y(a) = (e^{ma})(\cos a)$. Where $m = 0.005$.

Evaluate $(x(a))^2 + (y(a))^2$.

My attempt:

After substituting $m = 0.005$ into $x(a)$ and $y(a)$, I got $(x(a))^2 + (y(a))^2 = e^{(a/100)}$.

I can't go further. But the question is asking for evaluate, I am not sure if I need to find some exact numerical answers to the question or not. But without further information, i.e. the value of a, I am not sure how to find the exact numerical answers.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: O, thank you very much!